# Modifying the file upload dialog of firefox

Tags: file-upload, firefox-addon, xul

Is there any way to modify the file upload dialog in firefox with an extension (XUL or Javascript) ?

I'd like to give the user the possibility to encrypt the file(s) before uploading them to whereever (facebook, gmail, gmx, ...) and I thought the easiest way is to add a checkbox to the file upload dialog and check for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is **no native support** for something like that.

So you have to find a workaround to provide this possiblity.
The easiest way would most likely be to simply add the *checkbox near the file upload button* instead of directly in the dialog that shows up. Most likely it would even be noticed better like this.

An other way would be to create your *own file dialog* using other technologies like a java applet or some flash content. The advantage of this way is clearly, that you can handle all operation that have to be done for the encryption directly inside that applet. Then your firefox plugin would only have to trigger the loading of your applet for each file upload dialog.

Answer (score 0):

No. Internally [`nsIFilePicker` interface](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XPCOM_Interface_Reference/nsIFilePicker) is used to create this dialog - as you probably see there isn't a whole lot of configuration options. That's because Gecko will use the system's file selection dialog where available (Windows, Mac OS X) and changing this dialog is non-trivial to say the least. So even if you were creating this dialog yourself - you wouldn't be able to add a checkbox to it. You need to find some other solution.

Comment: What about `chrome://global/content/filepicker.xul`?

Comment: @lwburk: It's the dialog used if the operating system doesn't provide one (last time I checked that was only the case on Linux but this might have changed since).